# Not able to view a website in ubuntu?

Tags: browser, websites, quicktime

I am not able to view a particular website in ubuntu where as the same is getting viewed in windows. Can anyone suggest or provide me a fix to solve this issue??

#### Website which is not getting viewed in Ubuntu:

- http://www.grandsarovar.com/360/resturant.html

#### Getting viewed in windows:

[image]

#### View in Ubuntu:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This website consists basically of an embedded .mov (Apple Quicktime) movie. It may be Quicktime VR; I can't tell for sure as, even with the right set of plugins for quicktime playback, I'm unable to really see what was meant to be shown.

You can install the gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg plugin to get *some* .mov playback going, or you can google around for how to install some non-free codecs to get better .mov playback.

Personally I think this website's design is horrible as it's just an embedded video, and I'd strongly try to encourage the designer to make it more accessible and useful by coding with reasonable web standards and content, but that may not be a possibility here.

Comment: I can confirm it's Quicktime VR. Tested on Windows machine, and planning to send an email to the developer.